# Sql Server 2005 Replication: How to setup subscription with a sql script?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

When going through the replication setup wizard, I can choose Generate script at the end.  The script works fine for the Publication setup, however, when I run the generated script for Subscription setup, I run into issues and the replication doesn't work.  If however, I don't generate the script, but simply have the wizard start the replication itself, everything works.  I would really like to automate the subscription setup with a script.

The generated subscription script is:

```
-----------------BEGIN: Script to be run at Publisher 'SERVER\INSTANCE'-----------------
use [PublisherDatabase]
exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'PublicationName', @subscriber = N'server\instance', @destination_db = N'SubscriberDatabase', @subscription_type = N'Push', @sync_type = N'automatic', @article = N'all', @update_mode = N'read only', @subscriber_type = 0
exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent @publication = N'PublicationName', @subscriber = N'server\instance', @subscriber_db = N'SubscriberDatabase', @job_login = null, @job_password = null, @subscriber_security_mode = 1, @frequency_type = 64, @frequency_interval = 0, @frequency_relative_interval = 0, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 0, @frequency_subday_interval = 0, @active_start_time_of_day = 0, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 20091028, @active_end_date = 99991231, @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False', @dts_package_location = N'Distributor'
GO
-----------------END: Script to be run at Publisher 'FLANDERS\TESTING'-----------------
```

When I run the above script, it completes without errors. However, the subscription never shows up in the Sql Server Management Studio Replication->Local Subscriptions tree, and the data is never replicated.

Oddly however, running the query:

```
use distribution
select * from MSSubscriptions
```

gives the result set:

```
publisher_database_id publisher_id publisher_db                                                                                                                     publication_id article_id  subscriber_id subscriber_db                                                                                                                    subscription_type sync_type status subscription_seqno                 snapshot_seqno_flag independent_agent subscription_time       loopback_detection agent_id    update_mode publisher_seqno                    ss_cplt_seqno
--------------------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------- ----------- ------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------- --------- ------ ---------------------------------- ------------------- ----------------- ----------------------- ------------------ ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------- ----------------------------------
3                     0            PublisherDatabase                                                                                                                3              1           -1            virtual                                                                                                                          0                 1         1      0x00000027000001230003             0                   1                 2009-10-29 10:41:37.540 1                  10          0           0x00000027000001230003             0x00000027000001230003
3                     0            PublisherDatabase                                                                                                                3              1           -2            virtual                                                                                                                          0                 1         2      0x00000027000001230003             0                   1                 2009-10-29 10:41:37.603 1                  11          0           0x00000027000001230009             0x00000027000001230009
3                     0            PublisherDatabase                                                                                                                3              1           0             SubscriberDatabase                                                                                                               0                 1         1      0x000000270000013B0008             0                   1                 2009-10-29 10:54:58.140 1                  12          0           0x000000270000013B0008             0x000000270000013B0008
```

Which would seem to indicate the the subscription is present.

In case it matters, this is a push only publication/subscription, and both the publisher and subscriber databases are on the same server.

What else do I need to do to get subscriptions working from a sql script?

**edit:** cross-posted to http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic811043-291-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  When generating the subscription directly from management studio, it automatically starts the snapshot agent.  However, the script that management studio generates for the subscription does *not* start the snapshot agent.  Adding the following line to the generated script makes things work:

```
EXEC sp_startpublication_snapshot @publication = N'InstitutionPublication'
```

So my full script for the subscriber after modification is:

```
-----------------BEGIN: Script to be run at Publisher 'SERVER\INSTANCE'-----------------
-----------------BEGIN: Script to be run at Publisher 'SERVER\INSTANCE'-----------------
use [Profile]
exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'PublicationName', @subscriber = N'server\instance', @destination_db = N'destinationDatabaseName', @subscription_type = N'Push', @sync_type = N'automatic', @article = N'all', @update_mode = N'read only', @subscriber_type = 0
exec sp_addpushsubscription_agent @publication = N'PublicationName', @subscriber = N'server\instance', @subscriber_db = N'destinationDatabaseName', @job_login = null, @job_password = null, @subscriber_security_mode = 1, @frequency_type = 64, @frequency_interval = 0, @frequency_relative_interval = 0, @frequency_recurrence_factor = 0, @frequency_subday = 0, @frequency_subday_interval = 0, @active_start_time_of_day = 0, @active_end_time_of_day = 235959, @active_start_date = 20091104, @active_end_date = 99991231, @enabled_for_syncmgr = N'False', @dts_package_location = N'Distributor'
GO
-----------------END: Script to be run at Publisher 'SERVER\INSTANCE'-----------------

EXEC sp_startpublication_snapshot @publication = N'PublicationName';
GO
```